# design batch script for doing a big number of copies

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that copy 50 files from different sources to different destinations.
For now, I'm having 50 lines of:

```
xcopy "source" "dest" /y /v
```

Now, I want the script to end if one copy has been failed. The problem is that I don't want 100 lines like:

```
xcopy "source" "dest" /y /v
if not errorlevel 0 goto ERR
```

Is there a thing that act like a "function" in batch script?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes batch does have provisions for using functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with a file format of

```
d:\source\path1\*.*|n:\target\path\
d:\source\path2\*.*|n:\target\path3\
etc
```

Change the xcopy switches to suit your application.
Code largely take from npomaka.

Untested.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%D in (file.txt) do (
   xcopy "%%~D" "%%~E" s/h/e/k/f/c || goto :end_for
)
:end_for
```

Comment: Thank you both. I accept this answer because that is how I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%S in ("destination1|source1" 
           "destination2|source2"
            "and|so on") do (
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%D in ("%%~S") do (
       xcopy "%%~D" "%%~E" /y /v || goto :end_for
  )
)
:end_for
```

But you'll need to set in first `FOR` a mapping with source destination like this "destination1|source1"

Will thing for better solution (you already have a bat with all `xopy operations` ?)

If you already a `.BAT` with all sources->destinations you can try also :

```
for /f usebackq^ tokens^=1^,3^ delims^=^" %%S in ("your.bat") do (

    xcopy "%%~S" "%%~T" /y /v || goto :end_for

)
:end_for
```

.You can check also `robocopy` with `/R:0` . I think robocopy will be far more useful in your case.

Why do you have 50 lines? is there something common in the files that can be used as a mask?

Comment: Destination changes too.  Two files are needed or one file with `source|target` format could be used.

Comment: I have 3 different "destination folder" folder and 50 different "source files" paths.

Comment: The "list of source files" can be very big. This is not a problem?

Comment: # is a legal filename character.  Use a delimiter like | etc which will not be in a filename or path.  @Ofer: the format of the file needs to be like d:\source\path\*.*|n:\target\path\ assuming you use a pipe as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below offer these two features:

- It keep the list of file names in the same Batch file, so an additional file is not required.
- The list of names don't require any strange character, just the same names of your original file.

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^:FileList" "%~F0"') do set n=%%a
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('more +%n% "%~F0"') do (
   set source=
   for %%b in (%%a) do (
      if not defined source (set source=%%b) else set dest=%%b
   )
   xcopy !source! !dest! /y /v || goto end_for
)
:end_for
goto :EOF

:FileList
source dest
"\long\path\source number two" "\second dest folder"
```

This solution does not work if the names in the list contain wild-cards.